# Event Handler for ScatterViewItem Location Change in Surface SDK?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, scatterview

Does anyone know of an easy way to capture a ScatterViewItem's position (Center property) once it loses momentum and comes to a stop after being flicked across the screen?  I have a "hotspot" area set up that I'd like to initiate a file transfer from once the item comes to a stop within its bounds.

So far I've tried a PropertyChanged Notification with no success:

```
    ---OvelayWrapper.xaml.cs---
    ---------------------------
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Point CurrentLocation
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrentLocation;
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrentLocation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentLocation");
        }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string newLoc)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(newLoc));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("New Location Recorded");
    }


    ---OverlayWrapper.xaml---
    -------------------------
    <s:ScatterViewItem Center="{Binding Path=CurrentLocation}">
            <Label Content="Test" />
    </s:ScatterViewItem>
```

ScatterViewItems have a SizedChanged event handler that I use to track scaling with, but it doesn't make sense that a TranslationChanged event handler would not exist.

Also, I'm unable to make use of the ManipulationStarting/Delta/Completed events for a ScatterViewItem.

Thanks ahead of time,

-Z

Comment: A colleague suggested as a last resort use threading to do the tracking work.  I ended up implementing the **BackgroundWorker** class.  Although inefficient, it seems to be the only way of tracking the position of ScatterViewItems while in motion.  Maybe in the future I'll take advantage of the Affine2DInertiaCompleted event  if I replace ScatterViewItems with my own objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ScatterManipulationDelta for position, size, and rotation

Edit: delta not changed

Comment: I don't see **ScatterManipulationChanged** as being a field of the ScatterViewItem class.  I'm using the Surface 2.0 SDK, by the way.